# How to query EF 5.0 entities based on function of an entity?

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

```c#
public Product {

   public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}

   public bool IsExpired(){

       return ExpirationDate < DateTime.Now;
   }
}

db.Products.Where(c => c.IsExpired());
```

I get an error when I try to query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by forcing your datacontext to bring all objects back then making the query locally.

```
db.Products.AsEnumerable().Where(c => c.IsExpired());
or
db.Products.ToList().Where(c => c.IsExpired());
```

On SQL Profiler you will be getting a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Products
```

Then the objects will be filtered locally.